# Are Saddle Points only Possible in Non-Convex Functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis

Informally, I have heard that the following are only possible in Non-Convex Functions:

- **Saddle Points**
- **Local Minimums**

[image]

**My Question:** Is this in fact true - **Can we mathematically prove that Saddle Points and Local Minimums** *only* **possible in Non-Convex Functions?**

Or is this in fact just a general statement that is not completely true - and although not true in general, but it is in fact technically possible for Convex Functions to have Local Minimums and Saddle Points?

Can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

Comment: $f(x, y) = x^2+y^2$ is convex and has a local minimum.

Comment: This should answer your question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3437611/42969

Comment: @ Martin R: Thank you for your reply! I have already come across this question (and a few other questions on similar topics) - but I felt that none of the ones that I came across answered my question in enough detail.

Comment: @ Martin R: So many people in my life have told me that "saddle points and local minimums" are only possible in non-convex functions (e.g.  do a google images search) and you will see "saddle points and local minimums" being used as teaching examples to illustrate the properties of non-convex functions. But every time I asked these people who told me that "saddle points and local minimums are only possible in non-convex functions" - why this is true? Is it technically possible for saddle points and local minimums to exist in convex functions - no one ever had an answer for me

Comment: The only way answer that these people had, is that they would sketch an example (i.e. graph) of a 2 dimensional function on a piece of paper and "suggest" that it is impossible for a convex function to have a saddle point or local minimums - but I never felt that they answered my question properly. This is why I posted it here. Thank you so much!

Comment: Again: Convex function can have a local minimum, as the example $f(x, y) = x^2+y^2$ shows. And that are in fact the only possible critical points, as demonstrated in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3437611/42969. Which means that saddle-points and *strict local maxima* are only possible in non-convex functions.

Comment: @stats555 A function is convex if and only if it's epigraph is a convex set. This means at an inflection point the entire graph must be above the tangent hyperplane at that point. This implies it's a global minimum and so cannot be a saddle point.

Comment: @stats555 The single variable function labeled "convex" which is plotted in the leftmost graph you posted quite clearly has a local  minimum.

Comment: @ dxiv: thank you for your reply! i heard that in the case of the parabola, the local minimum is the same as the global minimum ... but I have been told that in general, the local minimum and global minimum can only be the same in convex functions?

Comment: @ CyclotomicField: thank you for teaching me about the word "epigraph"! Is the premise I have outlined in the question about saddle points and local minimums (with the exception of local minimums being equal to global minimums in convex functions) only occurring in non-convex functions true? thank you so much!

Comment: @stats555 "*I have been told that in general, the local minimum and global minimum can only be the same in convex functions*" $\;-\;$ That's certainly not true in general, take $\,f(x) = x^4-x^3\,$ or $\,f(x) = \sin x\,$ for example. You either misremember or misunderstood what you "*have been told*".

Comment: Mathematicians consider an absolute minimum to be a type of "local minimum." In the context of this question, does _local minimum_ of a function $f$ instead refer to a point $p$ where $f(p)$ is smaller than all values of $f$ at nearby points (i.e., in some neighborhood of $p$), but $p$ is not an absolute minimum of $f$...?